# AbsListView Consumes touch events

Tags: android, touch, widget

I have a ViewFlipper with several GridViews in it.  I want to be able to interact with the GridViews and swipe to switch from one grid to the other.  The problem that I an running AbsListView is consuming the touch events by returning true no matter what it has done.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374592/passing-touch-events-to-the-parent-view) that suggests that I try `onInterceptTouchEvent()` but that isn't working.  Since I'm trying to use a GestureDetector it seems to not be able to track the touches correctly.

Using the method in that post I am using `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to print out the touches that are intercepted, but I am not getting `MOTION_UP` events consistently.  I see a `MOTION_DOWN`, several `MOTION_MOVE`'s and no `MOTION_UP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, if anyone is looking for an answer to this here is the solution I came up with!  The basic set up is that I have a `FrameLayout` that contains a `ViewFlipper` and I add `GridView`s to the `ViewFlipper` based on how many items I have to show.  The I detect a swipe on the `FrameLayout` and switch between the `GridView`s in the `ViewFlipper`.  I still need to be able to click items in the `GridView` so I can't just consume the events in the `FrameLayout` but the `GridView` consumes any events that it gets so I had to intercept the events before they got to the `GridView` and give them to my `GestureDetector`.

```
public class PagedGrid extends FrameLayout
{
    private Context _context;
    private ViewFlipper _flipper;
    private GestureDetector _gestureDetector;

    public PresentationsGrid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.presentation_grid, this, true);

        _flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        _gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setClickable(true);

        _context = context;

        // ... Add Pages ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return _gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        _gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I subclassed the `GridView` to keep track of its state and pass events back sensibly.

```
public class UnNomableGridView extends GridView
{
    private boolean _wasDown;

    public UnNomableGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(!_wasDown && event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            _wasDown = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if(_wasDown && event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            _wasDown = false;
            return true;
        }
        else if(_wasDown && event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            _wasDown = false;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```