# dispatching touch events

Tags: android, touch

I have 12 horoscope sign images which are placed in 360 degree circular position. ImageButtons are being used to display the horoSignImages. ImageButton has selector that show pressed and unpressed states for horosSignImage. The signWheel rotates by using gestuer.

Problem is that, When i tap right over the horosignImage to rotate the wheel, the imageButton catches the event and wheel is not rotated upon scrolling the finger. I want to animate the image its pressed state when the user taps right over it, meanwhile the wheel should rotate if the user scrolls his finger. Wheel rotation only works if i tap outside the horosignImage and scroll the finger.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have the answer, but your problem seems to be similar to [Passing touch events to the parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374592/passing-touch-events-to-the-parent-view)

In both cases you want the touch event handled by the imageButton as well as the signWheel.