# how to create GridView and listview in expandablelistview

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, expandablelistview

In my project in first parent of expandablelistview have simple listview and other some parent have gridview layout. how to create that type of view. 
now i create simple expandablelistview here its code:-

```
public class ExpndListview extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ExpndParent> exParent;
    ArrayList<ExpndChild> exchild;
    String displaystatus = "0";

    public ExpndListview(Context context,ArrayList<ExpndParent> exParent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.exParent=exParent;
        //this.exchild=exchild;
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "in the Adapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<ExpndChild> chList=exParent.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final   View vi = convertView;

     final ExpndChild child=(ExpndChild)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView==null){

                LayoutInflater infalInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView=infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.dinkanddestsecondview, null);



        }

        TextView tvChild=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        TextView tvsub=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvsub);
        final TextView tvnum=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvnum);
        TextView tvadd=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvadd);
        TextView tvChildzh = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChildzh);
        TextView tvprice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        TextView tvid = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvid);


        //tvnum.setText("0");
        tvnum.setText(String.valueOf(child.getnum()));
        tvChildzh.setText(child.gettvChildzh());
        tvprice.setText("$"+child.gettvprice());
        tvprice.setTag(child.gettvprice());
        tvid.setText(child.gettvid());

        tvChild.setText(child.getname().toString());



        }


        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<ExpndChild> chList=exParent.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return exParent.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return exParent.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ExpndParent parentgroup=(ExpndParent)getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.expand_parent, null);
        }

        TextView tvGroup=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
        ImageView indi=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.indi);
        tvGroup.setText(parentgroup.getName());
         if (isExpanded) {
              indi.setImageResource(R.drawable.groupdown);
            } else {
                 indi.setImageResource(R.drawable.groupup);
            }
        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006480/gridview-inside-expandablelistview-with-multiple-choice-on-android

Comment: that i already check it. its not what i want