# Android set region to bubble clicks to underlying view

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, popupwindow, z-order

I have constructed something like the following:

[image]

It was done by creating a popupwindow and a layout inflater.  I first inflate a custom view that draws the circle, gradient, etc, and then inflate a layout file including the textviews and button.  I am wondering if there is a way, so that if the user clicks in the circular region, the clickEvent is bubbled through to the underlying region, thus making the underlying view handle the click.

Answer (score 1):

If you [return false from your touch event](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html), it will be passed the the view below.

Some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374592/passing-touch-events-to-the-parent-view)