# How to detect swipe gesture AND button click on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-event

I have an `ExpandableListView` and I am using a `SwipeDetector` to know when a row of this list is swiped.

The implementation of this dectetor comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340202/3571822).

Everything works fine.

Then, I have added a `Button` on each row and I want to be able to know:

- When the button is cliked
- When the row is swiped

This is the layout used for each (except for headers) row of the list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that the swipe gesture is no more detected because the `Button` catches the event. Since they are lots of threads about this subject I tried several things but nothing works (at least I did not manage to make it work). Here is the different things I tried:

- Set the `android:focusable` property to `false` on the `Button`
- Set the `android:descendantFocusability` property to `blocksDescendants` on the `RelativeLayout`
- Follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384443/3571822) and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent`

Last points:

- I can't set the `SwipeDetector` directly on the `Button` instead of the `ListView`'s item because in some cases there will be no button (or many).
- I can't use `android:clickable="false"` on the `Button` because I need to implement the `onClick` method.